# updating timer value in a UITableCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nstimer

I have a timer in which it calls the updateInterval every second. This timer will calculate the time remaining and put the result as a NSString. In other words the NSString is changing every second and from what I did below, the UITable is then reloaded every 1 second. The issue is that it crashes at `countdown.text = labelText;`

```
  // inside - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
//blah
 else if (indexPath.row == 1 && indexPath.section == 0){
        UILabel * countdown = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        countdown.text = labelText;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:countdown];
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Time remaining";
    }
//blah

- (void)updateInterval:(NSTimer *)timer {
    NSTimeInterval timeinterval = [(NSDate *)[data valueForKey:@"start_date"] timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]];

    // Get the system calendar
    NSCalendar *sysCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    // Create the NSDates
    NSDate *date1 = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    NSDate *date2 = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:timeinterval sinceDate:date1]; 

    // Get conversion to months, days, hours, minutes
    unsigned int unitFlags = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;

    NSDateComponents *breakdownInfo = [sysCalendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date1  toDate:date2  options:0];

    labelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d day %d:%d:%d", [breakdownInfo day], [breakdownInfo hour], [breakdownInfo minute], [breakdownInfo second]];
    //NSLog(@"%d day %d:%d:%d", [breakdownInfo day], [breakdownInfo hour], [breakdownInfo minute], [breakdownInfo second]);
    [self.table reloadData];
    [date1 release];
    [date2 release];

}
```

Why is this?

Comment: are you getting bad access in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting bad access in console then it may be because you have to retain labelText in your updateInterval method.

Comment: why do I have to retain the labelText again in the updateInterval?

Comment: You're assigning an unretained object to an ivar. At the end of its event loop, that object goes away. When updateInterval comes around, the ivar is pointing to released memory. You can better solve this by using a retained property for labelText rather than accessing your ivars directly (which is very error-prone).

Comment: what do you mean by a retained property for labelText?

Comment: property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *labelText;